# I have installed PostgreSQL via MacPorts, but cannot access it

Tags: postgresql, installation, macports

As I said in title, I've installed PostgreSQL usind MacPorts, but cannot access it.

The installation process was

```
$ sudo port install postgresql83-server
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/webcraft
$ sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/webcraft
$ sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/initdb -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/webcraft'
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql83-server.plist
```

My PATH is

```
/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin:/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I try to connect the server using psql client

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here is some info

```
$ ps ax | grep postgres | grep -v grep
   52   ??  Ss     0:00.00 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=postgresql83-server --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql83-server/postgresql83-server.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql83-server/postgresql83-server.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql83-server/postgresql83-server.wrapper restart ; --pid=none
```

Comment: After system restart `launchctl list | grep macport` returns nothing. Why?

Comment: I'm going to install PostgreSQL view Homebrew.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try running:

```
which psql
```

I imagine psql is still referencing `/usr/bin/psql`, and the macports version of psql is suffixed with the version number, in your case psql83.  You can alias psql to psql83 as a simple workaround.  Better would be to change the default:

```
sudo port select --set postgresql postgresql83
```

That will do the proper routing.

Answer (score 11):

There is a very easy solution to this, but it's not well documented in my opinion:

MacPorts encourages installing their `*_select` ports to manage potentially multiple versions of software (say you want Postgres93 and Postgres94 at the same time). It's a great feature, but it adds an extra step that is for some reason rarely mentioned in the docs:

```
$ sudo port install postgresql94-server
```

#### Many failed attempts at starting the server later..

```
$ sudo port install postgresql_select
$ sudo port select postgresql
Available versions for postgresql:
    none (active)
    postgresql94
```

#### Well that can't be good!

```
$ sudo port select postgresql postgresql94
$ sudo port load postgresql94-server
```

#### You're kidding me. Now it's running?

Simply installing Postgres doesn't fully setup symlinks to make it easily runnable. Installing `postrgresql_select` gives MacPorts the information it needs to do that via `port select`. Once you've selected the active version of your choice, starting the Posgres server via `luanchctl` is as easy as `port load postgresqlXX-server`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very late answer and doesn't answer your full question, but launchctl will show different results depending on if you are superuser or not.

Try doing:

sudo launchctl list | grep postgres

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem on my MacBook Pro. I could resolve the problem after I rode this blog post here and all the comments:

http://benscheirman.com/2010/06/installing-postgresql-for-rails-on-mac-os-x

The Problem is that postgres is not really running. I recognized this after I did a port scan to my own machine and realized that nothing is running on Port 5432.

I created a small script "start_pg_server.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su postgres -c 'pg_ctl start -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/defaultdb/'
```

after executing this script the server was running and I could connect me with pgAdmin. I was also able to run my ruby stuff with rake db:create and rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 2):

After I restored using Timemachine I had the same problem.
The reason was that the permissions were mangled and postgres could not write the pid file.
Running this solved it for me:

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/
sudo port unload postgresql91-server
sudo port load postgresql91-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance create your postgres user with a shell of /usr/bin/false? If so, the startup script won't work because it uses su which passes commands you send it through the shell.

If you did set it to /usr/bin/false, try changing it to /bin/bash and that might fix things.